# How to replace string "\n" with a line separator?

Tags: objective-c

For example my string is

```
NSString *blabla=@"qwerty\n mix";
```

In output I need:

```
qwerty
mix
```

Comment: what is your current output? how do you output it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *which output* you mean. But on the console and in `UILabel` the `\n` works for me.

### Code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *aString = @"first line\nsecond line";
        NSLog(aString);
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
2014-06-10 11:24:46.507 Untitled[608:507] first line
second line
```

---

To format it better you could write it as multiple strings:

```
        NSString *aString = @"first line"
        "\n"
        "second line";
```

Output is the same

Comment: Added another option to make the `\n` better visible.

Answer (score 0):

If `\n` is not working and you are setting text to a label don't forget to set `numberOfLines` to `0`. If you have a label property it would look like this:

```
self.yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Also watch out when reading a string from XML or SQLite. The parsed linebreak will not work in a UILabel. You will have to replace the parsed `\\n` with hard coded `\n`:

```
//NSString * stringForLabel = INPUT;
NSString *lineBreak = @"\n";
stringForLabel = [stringForLabel stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:lineBreak];

self.yourLabel.text = stringForLabel;
```